# Discovering component identifiers of a SAP transaction' fields to utilize

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, sap-gui

Through a lot of Googling I managed to connect to SAP and open a transaction from VBA code. This is not part of the problem, so I won't include it here.

My problem is as follows: Now that I have the transaction open, I want to enter values into the fields of the transaction from my code.

I assume this is done by code similar to this:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVendor").Text
```

However, the /usr/ctxtVendor part is obviously wrong. If I understand correctly, this is pretty much different on a company basis.

One solution is to use the "SAP Script Recording & Playback" utility to generate VBA code and extract the variablenames. Unfortunately I am not authorized to use this, and I won't be any time soon so that is not an option.

EDIT: [I found a second solution:](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_scm700_ehp02/helpdata/en/c7/e9391ee7c54728a59e5354f85c207d/content.htm)but it doesn't seem as if I have access to this.

Are there other ways of discovering the identifiers for this and other transactions?

Thank you for reading and hopefully for providing an answer.

Comment: You can try press F1 in each field, and technical info. not sure if this works for buttons etc...

Comment: '/usr' typically represents the main user input area, and then there is stuff for the information bar at the bottom, as well as toolbars like 'tbar' etc

Comment: Thank you for the comments! They are giving me more information than I had before!

@MacroMarc; What fields am I looking for? https://imgur.com/a/8r8Y5oW I've tried (.../usr/MEPO_NAME).TEXT = "text" but that doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry i gave you the wrong info for VBA scriptable names. Make your window a variable like so:

```
Dim window As SAPFEWSELib.GuiFrameWindow
Set window = session.FindById("wnd[0]")
```

Then you go to the Locals window in your VBEditor, and see it here:

[image]

For me, the /usr area is Item 5 of the window children, open it up and look for all the fields listed. You can use the path provided. E.g. Below i have opened up Item 2 which is Account number, and you see the string needed in Id property.

[image]

Then you use it like so:

```
window.FindById("usr/ctxtRACCT-LOW").Text = "A123456"
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing. I just managed to edit a field in SAP from my code! For shits and giggles, my variable is under "/usr/ctxtEKKO-LIFNR", I couldn't have ever found that without your help so thank you! If you know of any ways that I can simulate pressing a button in SAP, that would be wonderful too!

Comment: Apparantly EKKO is an SAP table and LIFNR a field in there, the more you know!

Comment: `window.FindById("tbar[1]/btn[40]").Press`

Comment: Hello Marc, Thank you again for all the help! However, I've run into some problems with the ID's and I think you're the only person right now that could possibly help me out. There is no way to reach out to you privately through SO, so I'll drop my email here, please send me an email so we can come in contact Marc! FTR it's about this kind of ID: /app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/subSUB0:SAPLMEGUI:0013/subSUB2:SAPLMEVIEWS:1100/subSUB2:......./ctxtMEPO1222-EKORG" (it's so long I have to manually type it since coping only copies like 150-170 characters...